# .NET WindowService, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload is not getting called when Stoping the Service

Tags: .net, windows-services, window, c#-2.0

I have a .NET window Service which extend a custom base class, this serves as base for many windows services i have written so far, now i want to do add some monitor (hearbeat) on this base class, on the initialized of the base class i start a thread that will notify a database and sleep for 40 sec, *this is not perfect but serves its purpouse so far*. I have registered an event for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.**DomainUnload**, to stop the heartbeat threads, but when i stop the Window Service, my database updates are stopped but the logs that i have place in the event registered at AppDomain.CurrentDomain.**DomainUnload**  are not appearing in the Event Viewer, so i dont have a clear indication if the event is getting fired or not.

I cannot place my heartbeat initialization into the OnStart / OnStop of my base classes, since it will require to recompile all my windows service to make sure all of them all call base.OnStart / base.OnStop.

Any idea why the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.**DomainUnload** is not getting fired

ps.

I tried also with AppDomain.CurrentDomain.**ProcessExit** with the same result as above, no logs in the EventViewer .

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger and stepping through it?

Comment: Yes i did it, once i stop the thread the debugger disconnect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the "CurrentDomain" the default app domain? I would guess so, unless you create custom domains. If so, then note that [DomainUnload is not raised for the default domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.domainunload%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

As for `ProcessExit`, I'm not sure, but note that a Windows Service's lifetime is not necessarily bound to the process' lifetime that hosts it. If a process hosts more than one Windows Service it will only exit, when all services are stopped.

Comment: I should had check the Documentation, you are correct. But what i really don't understand is the following. I would expect to have a Dangling thread if nobody is break the loop of the thread, but that doesn't seem the case here. My Database Update are stopped once i stop the service but im not seeing any logs in the Event Viewer with the evidence of this happening.

Comment: Your thread is being stopped, eventually. The (default) domain is destroyed, eventually. You're just not getting an event for that.